# iText7. When using HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements to convert a <li> the font size assigned is not working

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7, pdfhtml

I am using iText7 to generate pdf documents.
In one of the parts i need to show some data stored in HTML so I am using pdfHtml HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements().
When the HTML string is comming with

I am not able to set the fontSize to the elements inside the list.
ConvertToElements is creating a system.Collections.Generic.List<iText.Layout.Element.IElement where one of the elements is iText.Layout.Element.List.
Inside this List I get the listItems with the fontSIze property = 12f even if I am setting all the paragraphs, divs and the document fontSize to 9

Also I am not able to iterate through ListItems in order to change properties manually...

This how my code looks like at this moment, after trying a lot of different things:

```
private void CreateParagraphsFromHTML(PrintableDTO printable)
        {
            ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
            properties.SetFontProvider(FProvider);
            
            var htmlString = printable.Text;
            var elements = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(htmlString, properties);
            Div div = new Div();
            div.SetFontSize(9f);
            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                if(element is Paragraph)
                {
                    Paragraph p = (Paragraph)element;
                    p.GetChildren().ForEach(c => c.SetProperty(24, new UnitValue(1, 9f)));
                    p.SetFontSize(9f)
                            .SetMarginBottom(0.1f)
                            .SetMarginTop(0.1f);
                    div.Add(p);

                }
                else
                {
                    element.SetProperty(24, new UnitValue(1, 9f));
                    Paragraph p = new Paragraph().SetFontSize(9f);
                    p.Add((IBlockElement)element);                    
                    div.Add(p);

                }
            }
            Document.Add(div);
        }
```